# How to delete the groups a user belongs when deleting the user in OpenLDAP through JNDI

Tags: openldap

I can successfully delete OpenLDAP users from Java JNDI but the "member" entries in the groups that user belongs remain unchanged (yes, this is not JPA and no cascade delete thing :-) )
I wonder which is the best approach to, before deleting a user, finding which groups the user belongs to and deleting those "member" entries.

BTW, I use groupOfNames objectClass approach for groups: including entries in the groups the user belongs to (I liked the approach of using "member" and groupOfNames in the user,not the group, but in OpenLDAP it seems to be complicated because of the conflict in structural objectClasses between InetOrgPerson and groupOfNames.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the referential integrity overlay `refint` and it will happen automatically.